# Custom "Markdown"-style tags

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I want to create custom tags for different things like bold, underline and italic without using a Markdown library/class.

For example

```
*Bold text*
/Italic text/
_Underlined text_
```

So the above would be changed to:

```
<strong>Bold text</strong>
<em>Italic text</em>
<u>Underlined text</u>
```

I have no idea where to begin and have been searching for a solution for ages.

I read a few tutorials on regular expressions but still unsure how to approach this.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try a replace, show at least some effort.

Comment: I did, but I don't know how to replace the first instance with an open tag and the second with a close tag.

I just end up with `<strong>Bold text<strong>`

Comment: Do put the regex replacement you used in your question to get this result.

Comment: No, I used str_replace. I don't know much about regex but I've read that this kind of stuff is possible with regular expressions.

Comment: Time for you to learn more regex then. If you want to use it, gotta learn it. Look into capture groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a recursive function to do that with regex. The tricky part (for me) was the use of forward slash `/` which is also used in the close tags. So at first i insert `{}` and replaces those with `/` in the very end.

test text :

```php
$input ="
*Bold text*
bla bla bla
/Italic text/
bla bla bla
_Underlined text_
bla bla bla
";
```

replace function :

```php
function markdown(&$text, $code, $tag, $open) {
    if (strpos($text, $code)) {
        $insertTag=($open) ? '<'.$tag.'>' : '<{}'.$tag.'>';
        $reg='['.preg_quote($code).']';
        $text=preg_replace($reg, $insertTag, $text, 1);
        markdown($text, $code, $tag, !$open);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

run :

```php
markdown($input, '*', 'strong', true);
markdown($input, '/', 'em', true);
markdown($input, '_', 'u', true);
$input=str_replace('{}', '/', $input);
echo $input;
```

outputs :

```html
<strong>Bold text</strong>
bla bla bla
<em>Italic text</em>
bla bla bla
<u>Underlined text</u>
bla bla bla
```